# How to capture & modify content of emails I sent/receive?

Tags: c#, winforms, email, proxy

I gonna develop a windows app that get content of emails I send/receive; because I need to access their details such as: Title, Text, timestamp, Sender, Receiver & etc. in my application.

Wireshark can capture all kind of packets are passing through a network-interface (including IMAP) but it can't MODIFY their content; And that's what I need.

Any idea of how to capture & modify email packets ?

Comment: If it's really **yours** emails and you're not trying to create mail sniffer - why don't your application simply login to IMAP server using your credentials and get access to your emails?

Comment: Hah! No, I don't want to sniff anything! Actually my app should capture any IMAP traffics (the email contents) go through my system. Imagine I login to my gmail account, then I send or receive an email; Now my app should get all of their contents to save them on my system automatically.

Comment: So why don't you app just login to your Gmail account via IMAP and get access to your messages? Capturing traffic is fully unnessesary in the case described by you.

Comment: http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/Download/Downloads/ - here is Lumisoft.NET library. which is pretty good working with IMAP

Comment: So, if you developing app that sends email. Lets say you use EWS. There we go - you have access to all your mailbox content. I recently developed application that reads meeting requests, etc. Best way is to use some API from the email provider, which you're going to integrate your app with

Comment: "No, I don't want to sniff anything! Actually my app should capture any IMAP traffics" - That's what sniffing is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what I need: An application-based **TCP/IP proxy**

A tcp/ip proxy can capture all tcp/ip traffics (including email packets) and even modify their content.
Like what Tamper-Data (a fireFox add-ons) or FiddlerCore do for HTTP/HTTPS.